# "value.toString(...).toUppercase is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my vue component I have an "uppercase" filter to tranform strings into uppercase, however I'm gettinh the following error:

```
TypeError: "value.toString(...).toUppercase is not a function"
```

This is my filter:

```
Vue.filter('uppercase', function (value) {
    console.log(typeof value); // this returns string
    if (!value) return '';
    value = value.toString().toUppercase();
    return value;
});
```

Comment: `toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the calling of the function `toUpperCase()`.

Ref URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to upper the 'c' at the name of the function like that `.toUpperCase()` and not `.toUppercase()`

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled the uppercase function.
The right function for uppercase is  `toUpperCase()`